# AHKV1: GetKeyState() not working with #if

Tags: autohotkey

The following does not work. The tooltips never fire, when I am holding control:

```
#singleinstance, force
#Persistent

#If GetKeyState("LControl", "p") 
   WheelUp::
       tooltip, WheelUp + lctrl
       Return
   WheelDown::
       tooltip, WheelDown + lctrl
       Return
#If
```

But this works, pressing `a` while `ctrl` is down fires the tooltip `ctrl is down`:

```
#singleinstance, force
#Persistent

*~a::
    if GetKeyState("LControl", "p")
        tooltip, ctrl is down
    else
        tooltip, ctrl is not down
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Wildcard(*)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard): Fires the hotkey even if extra modifiers (in this case LControl) are being held down.

```
#If GetKeyState("LControl", "p") 

   *WheelUp:: tooltip, WheelUp + lctrl
   *WheelDown:: tooltip, WheelDown + lctrl

#If
```

Except in special cases, it is recommended to use the standard syntax:

```
<^WheelUp:: tooltip, WheelUp + lctrl
<^WheelDown:: tooltip, WheelDown + lctrl
```

See [Hotkey Modifier Symbols](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols).